# How do I Sort Object Properties by one of their Properties (Not sorting an array)?

Tags: php, oop

So I've found a ton of answers regarding sorting arrays and sorting an array of objects by those object properties. But how can I rearrange the order of properties in an object via sorting.

I have an object that is laid out kind of like this:

```
$My_Object->tabs->tab_1->priority = 3;
$My_Object->tabs->tab_2->priority = 5;
$My_Object->tabs->tab_3->priority = 1;
```

I've tried the following code without any affect whatsoever.

```
public function sort_by_priority() {

    usort( $this->tabs , array( $this , 'compare' ) );

}

public function compare($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->priority, $b->priority);
}
```

$this->sort_by_priority() is being called within a class context.

But no matter what I try, the object properties are ALWAYS in the order they were added to the object.

It should return in this order: tab_3, tab_1, tab_2.

How can I sort the order of the properties within an object according to that priority property?

Here is a link to the actual object that I'm attempting to sort: https://gist.github.com/Nicholas-Cardot/d97cf6c88243fb9b2745a1d2edee19d3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it.

```
public function sort_by_priority() {
    $tabs = new ArrayObject($this->tabs);
    $tabs->uasort(function($a, $b){
        return (int)$a->priority - (int)$b->priority ;
    });
}
```

Comment: This was close enough that it got me to the solution. Had to change $a->pro to $a->priority. Also, had to write a intcmp() function to evaluate integers the same way that strcmp() evaluates strings. Now it works right as rain.

Comment: It was my fault. I forgot to change it back. Ha ha.

Comment: If you add this, then your answer will be absolutely a perfect solution to my question:  public function intcmp($a,$b) {
     if((int)$a == (int)$b)return 0;
     if((int)$a  > (int)$b)return 1;
     if((int)$a  < (int)$b)return -1;
 }